# How do you use MapReduce/Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm looking for some general information about how other people are using [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/core/) or other MapReduce-like technologies. In general, I am curious to whether you are writing MR applications to process existing data sets (like web server log files), or are you writing applications that generate and process new data sets?

**Edit:**
Follow-up Questions

(1) Do you ever execute a MR program against data generated by other MR programs?

(2) Do you ever need to modify existing data sets using MR?

(3) Do you ever share your data sets with other developers?

Comment: This is an old posting. I have already published my research paper on MapReduce. More information (and our benchmark source code) can be found here:


[http://database.cs.brown.edu/projects/mapreduce-vs-dbms/](http://database.cs.brown.edu/projects/mapreduce-vs-dbms/)

Answer (score 10):

Checkout the [PowerdBy Hadoop](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/PoweredBy) wiki for examples of everything from Facebook to FOX News and how they are using it.

Answer (score 2):

I am analyzing existing data sets, in my case traces of programmer activity.

Answer (score 1):

I have used hadoop as part of [nutch](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/), and for building/analyzing web-graphs and text

(1) Many tasks cannot be done in one go, so the need to run MR on MR-generated data is essential.

(2) When crawling with nutch, there are situations when you need to filter or normalize the crawldb or other data. (So, yes)

(3) So far mainly as dumps or results in some kind. Not as "native" MR-data so far.

Answer (score 1):

> In general, I am curious to whether you are writing MR applications to
>   process existing data sets (like web server log files), or are you
>   writing applications that generate and process new data sets?

The work that I am doing with MR applications involves processing existing data sets that can be used to generate new data sets, which...

> (1) Do you ever execute a MR program against data generated by other MR programs?

...yes I do. This is known as chaining Map/Reduce operations, where you link multiple map and reduce jobs in sequence.

> (2) Do you ever need to modify existing data sets using MR?

The idea of MR is to throw in your existing data set and not really have to modify it in order to process and analyze information out of it. The only case where I have had to do that is with splitting a data set into parcels.

> (3) Do you ever share your data sets with other developers?

A lot of the code that is involved in active MR applications is considered proprietary as is mine, so sharing it with other developers is somewhat of an issue; if you want sample data sets to work with the books that I recommend are Pro Hadoop (Venner), Hadoop in Action (Lam), and Hadoop the Definitive Guide (White).

Answer (score 0):

My two uses so far have been analysis of large behavioral data sets (gathered from the web, mobile handsets, &c) and parallelizing approaches to large problems (e.g., using genetic algorithms to find local optima in an NP-complete problem space).

In the general case, MR flows are multi-stage, so I'm frequently running against data generated by an earlier MR stage.